# Набережная им. Ленина

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, топонимика

***Набережная им. Ленина** в Ялте*. Стоит ли писать набережную как улицу с большой буквы? Или набережных в Крыму много, а это одна из таких, то есть нарицательное слово?

Answer (score 1):

Это слово в данном топониме пишется с маленькой буквы:

*набережная имени Ленина*

Точнее:

*Ленина В.И. имени набережная*

Конкретно этот объект в ГАР (посмотреть можно, например, через [ФИАС](https://fias.nalog.ru/)) определён именно типом *набережная*, а родовые понятия в составе имен географических объектов пишутся с маленькой буквы.

Для сравнения, в Челябинске есть *улица Университетская Набережная*, определяемая как *улица*, поэтому слово *Набережная* в её названии пишется с заглавной буквы.

Comment: _Точнее: Ленина В.И. имени набережная_. Господи, и **где** ж Вы такую точность, такой адрес, такую табличку видели?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае действует следующее правило:
в названиях улиц, площадей, переулков, проспектов с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме **родовых терминов** (то есть самих слов *улица, площадь, набережная* и тому подобных), а также слов *года, лет, имени*.

Правильно: набережная имени Ленина; наб. им. Ленина; [набережная Ленина](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1.%20%D0%B8%D0%BC.%20%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-gszs3KPvAhVYAxAIHVLhC6MQjJkEegQIEhAB&cshid=1615310607889597&biw=1366&bih=657).

Сравните: [набережная Обводного канала](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1.%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=dpvu6lllWF2YSM%252C72rr2yfP6QjLdM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTKGnAIS7SjoNqflGb0x4S-b6O1xQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhsuKt3KPvAhW_AxAIHfMRBIYQ9QF6BAgDEAE&cshid=1615310538525940#imgrc=dpvu6lllWF2YSM), набережная Макарова, набережная Кутузова, набережная Робеспьера.

Но с того мгновения, когда он на **набережной Фонтанки** отдал незнакомой женщине привезенный с собой хлеб и решил спасти ее и детей, он беспрестанно находился в каком-то особом душевном состоянии... [Н. К. Чуковский. Балтийское небо (1946-1953)]

...а я, когда бываю в Москве, живу у них в большой квартире многоэтажного и многоподъездного дома на **набережной Тараса Шевченко**. [Евгений Рубин. Пан или пропал. Жизнеописание (1999-2000)]

[Набережные Санкт-Петербурга](http://www.peterburg.biz/naberezhnye.html)
["Грамота": *набережная*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

Если не в начале предложения, то «набережная имени Ленина» — только так. В названиях все слова пишут с заглавной буквы, за исключением родового слова или статуса, гидронимов (реки, речки, канала, ручей, канавки, острова), предлогов, слов имени, лет, года, съезда, стороны, области. Таких исключений не так много.

А вот в названии «Набережная улица» конечно всегда с заглавной.